# I can't get past 'Android resource linking failed' error

Tags: java, php, android, xampp

- **Error is as follows**

```
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:AAPT: C:\Users\Sifundo\AndroidStud
ioProjects\LoginRegistration\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4612: error: resource color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector (aka com.example.loginregistration:color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector) not found.
C:\Users\Sifundo\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginRegistration\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4626: 
error: resource color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector (aka com.example.loginregistration:color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector) not found.
C:\Users\Sifundo\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginRegistration\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4612: error: resource color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector (aka com.example.loginregistration:color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector) not found.
C:\Users\Sifundo\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginRegistration\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4626: error: resource color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector (aka com.example.loginregistration:color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

I have added the mtrl_btn_text_color_selector.xml file to res/color folder with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright 2017 The Android Open Source Project
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: can you post your XML code here?

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the namespace.

> it should start with http://

Check this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Oh I do have http:// in my namespace, something must've went wrong when I was pasting the code

Comment: your code is working fine in my system. please check again!

Comment: also, where did you put the XML? in the color directory?

Comment: Yes, the XML file is in the color folder. Just am not sure if I have the right code in it, because i took it from github